# Nodejs : async.eachSeries calling final callback too early

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, coffeescript

I really shortened the code to put the main parts :

I have a list and I want to make some operations to each items of that list. For that I'm using async.eachSeries. Thing is , I have  2 asynchronous functions inside the loop namely `async.parallel` and `create_media_iso` which is the success callback of `async.parallel`.

My problem is that after the fist item is executed, the final callback is triggered `$location.path "/wait_media"`. However I can see that in the background other items are executing.

Can anyone point me in the good direction please ?

Any advices is appreciated.

```
async.eachSeries myList, ((entry, callback) ->

  media_file              = entry
  extension               = path.extname media_file
  media_media             = path.basename media_file, extension
  media                   = {file: media_file, media: media_media}

  work_path = path.join binaries_iso_path, media.media

  copy_list_functions = get_media_copy_list media, work_path, $scope.copy_complete


  async.parallel copy_list_functions, (err, res) ->

      create_media_iso media_iso, media.media, work_path, boot_image_path, sort_file_path, (progress) ->
          $scope.count = progress

          if $scope.count >= 100.0                
              callback()
  return

), (err) ->
    if err
      console.log 'A file failed to process'
    else
      $location.path "/wait_media"
    return
```

Answer (score 1):

`async.parallel copy_list_functions` returns immediately without waiting for the function to finish. That's why outer callback is called . Try calling `copy_list_functions` sequentiality.

Comment: Any advices to make it sequential ? Heard about async.series ?

Comment: What will happen if you remove `async.parallel`  and just call `copy_list_functions` with params?

Comment: Nothing will happen since `async.parallel` first paramater is a list of functions that'll run, if I don't call it, the functions inside won't run